# When enumerating a list of tuples I get TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, csv, tuples, typeerror

The script below reads a CSV file and creates a list of tuples called `people`. The tuple is the `patron_id` (a unique string identifier) and a dictionary of `person` information.

For a sample of data (simplified with name info removed) looking like this:

```
patron_id    show_id
1111MAIN       MW1
2222SCOTT      MW2
1111MAIN       MW1
```

The script should output a list of tuples, that looks like this:

`[
  ("1111MAIN", {'patron_id': "1111MAIN", 'show_list': ["MW1", "MW2"]}),
  ("2222SCOTT", {'patron_id': "2222SCOTT", 'show_list': ["MW2"]})
 ]`

The script raises the following error in traceback:

`File "frequency.py", line 75, in <module>
   main("input.csv")
 File "frequency.py", line 35, in main
   person_index = [x for x, y in enumerate[people] if y[0] == patron_id]`

When I test this line manually in the shell it returns the index of the tuple for which I am searching. Why is this line failing in the script?

```
import csv

def main(filename):
    people = [] #list of person tuples
    person = {} #patron info with list of unique shows

    #open csv data
    csv_file = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'))

    #read and define CSV data
    for record in csv_file:
        show_list = []

        patron_id = record[0]
        first_name = record[1]
        last_name = record[2]
        show_name = record[3]

        #check if this is the first row
        if len(people) == 0:
            show_list.append(show_name)
            person = (patron_id, {'patron_id': patron_id, 'first_name': first_name, 'last_name': last_name, 'show_list': show_list})
            people.append(person)

        else:

            #if this person IS in the list of people
            if any(patron_id in person for person in people) == True:
                #retrieve this person from people by finding its index          
                person_index = [x for x, y in enumerate[people] if y[0] == patron_id][0]
```

Comment: `enumerate[people]`-> `enumerate(people)`

Comment: I feel ridiculous. If you will post that as an answer I will select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as stated in my comment, the problem is that you try to call the `__getitem__` method of `enumerate` by using square brackets, which is bound to fail because it does not have this method. To construct an enumerate object, use parentheses.

Try to pay close attention to the error messages, often they are helpful. I did not need to read your whole code to find the error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help - like I said, I feel silly!

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `enumerate[people]` to `enumerate(people)`.  When you use brackets, python thinks you trying to access `enumerate` at position `people`.  Instead, you need to call it.

Comment: I marked timgeb as the answer because he beat you to it, but as a comment - this is exactly right though.